# Row Ids not assigned with vue ag-grid

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I'm trying to have user-defined row-ids to prevent rerendering instead of Application assigned Ids as described in [Vue ag-grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/row-ids/#application-assigned-ids). However, unique row-ids are not getting assigned to the rows and the callback getRowId is not been called and it's adding the row-ids as 0,1,2,.....
From the documentation, it's not clear at which point in time the callback is called to assign the user-provided row-ids.

I'm using "vue": "^2.6.11" and "@ag-grid-community/vue": "^26.1.0"

Model

```
<template>
  <div>
      <template>
        <ag-grid-vue
          style="height: calc(100vh - 148px)"
          class="ag-theme-balham"
          :columnDefs="columnDefs"
          @grid-ready="onGridReady"
          :rowData="rowData"
          :getRowId="getRowId"
        ></ag-grid-vue>
      </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "My-Component",
  data() {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: "Row ID", valueGetter: "node.id" },
        { field: "id" },
        { field: "make" },
        { field: "model" },
        { field: "price" },
      ],
      gridApi: null,
      columnApi: null,

      rowData: null,
      getRowId: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.rowData = [
      { id: "c1", make: "Lima", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { id: "c2", make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { id: "c8", make: "Porsche", model: "Boxster", price: 72000 },
      { id: "c4", make: "BMW", model: "M50", price: 60000 },
      { id: "c14", make: "Aston Martin", model: "DBX", price: 190000 },
    ];
    this.getRowId = (params) => {
      return params?.data.id;
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see any issue in your code. However, you can try upgrading the version from 26 to 29. Here is a working demo with this version- https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-vue-example-forked-j7wsuz?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't read the ag-drid documentation clearly.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    style="height: calc(100vh - 148px)"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    @onGridReady="onGridReady"
    :rowData="rowData"
    :getRowId="getId"
  ></ag-grid-vue>
</template>
<script>
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        { headerName: "Row ID", valueGetter: "node.id" },
        { field: "make" },
        { field: "model" },
        { field: "price" },
      ],
      gridApi: null,
      columnApi: null,

      rowData: null,
      getRowId: null,
      getId: (params) => {
        return params.data.id;
      },
    };
  },
  components: {
    AgGridVue,
  },
  created() {
    this.rowData = [
      { id: "c1", make: "Lima", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { id: "c2", make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { id: "c8", make: "Porsche", model: "Boxster", price: 72000 },
      { id: "c4", make: "BMW", model: "M50", price: 60000 },
      { id: "c14", make: "Aston Martin", model: "DBX", price: 190000 },
    ];
  },
  methods: {
    onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSNN4.png)

Comment: Would you please explain your answer, and the snippet is also not working.

Comment: from your code i can see you are new to ag-grid right? and you arefollowing the tutoril. The problem is you missed one function onGridReady,i didnt see this under created.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-vue-example-forked-wq53ou?file=/src/App.vue   try here if it works the way you wanted. or just replace your code with mine. I'm sure it works.

Comment: Hey, I really don't see the difference between the sandbox link I mentioned and yours. Besides, would you explain your answer that how this should work and what things are missing from OP's side?

Comment: sorry for my bad english. I dont see the code below in your script part: methods: {
    onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    },
  }     jsut add this part you will see it works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. IMO, missing `onGridReady` is not the reason because if you will remove it, it will work still. Second thing, OP has version 26, and your code-sandbox is using version 29 of ag-vue-grid. So this is what I added in the comment. Please let me know if I didn't get your insights.

Comment: yeah, you got me right. and its my bad i forgot about the VG version. I just tried to change it to 26,it doest work anymore. so i guess the old version deosnt support getRowID?

Comment: :) thanks, then maybe you should update your answer.

Comment: it seems the only solution is uptae it to higher version.